# Sharepoint workflow 2010 - document versioning - Content type - field do not get updated

Tags: workflow, document-library, content-type, versioning

I've got a custom list with a CT  (master list). When creating a new list item a workflow kickes in and creates a new document based on a CT in another document library.

Problem is when I update a element in master they do not appear in the document library. Seems like the field (site column) entry just got deleted! If I change the workflow to "Append a unique idendifier to the end of the file name" everything works like it should! But not when I use "Overwrite the existing file".

I've tried to reenable versioning, but it seems to have the same problem!

I've also removed all workflows in the list, and deployed the workflow without any luck!

Yes I've also running the workflow on create / change / manually ..

Comment: How are you updating the document fields?

Comment: dumb question, but is your workflow set to fire on item change too?

Comment: @AmalHashim From the master custom list I have a workflow. In the workflow I have a step that create a new list item in the document library. Inside it I've "mapped" all related fields

Comment: @PirateEric yes the workflow runs every time on create / change / manually